# the list of tables are not showing on my tables after downloading dvdrental sample database, using pgadmin4

Tags: database, postgresql-12

I am loading a database with pgadmin4 and postgresql12, have downloaded the postgrelsql12 and DVD rental sample database, I successful launched my pgadmin4, and restored my database, its showing tables but I cant find the list of 15 tables that comes with the sample database. it supposed to be showing the number of tables besides the table when I click the dropdown icon, but nothing shows, I cant see or access the tables from the sample database I downloaded.